# Tela de Fragment para chamar outra tela Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

Eu estou em um `fragment`, e nesse `fragment` eu quero chamar outra tela que também é um `fragment`. Estou usando `recycleview`. Se eu tentar chamar uma `activity`, eu consigo, mas não consigo chamar um `fragment`.

Veja o código abaixo:

```
@Override
public void onNoteClick(int position) {
    listaCursos.get(position);
   // aqui deve chamar outro fragment
}
```

Tentei alguns exemplos que achei, mas não abre uma outra tela que tem o `fragment`.
 Só lembrando que meu app só possui uma `activity`, todo o resto somente `fragment`.

Chamar a tela usando intent não é meu caso.

Tentei algo parecido com isso que achei e não foi:

```
Fragment fr = new Fragment();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Vou colocar aqui como ta meu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
tools:context=".fragmentos.consultarCursoUrl">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CONSULTAR CURSO"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >





    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/codigo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Código"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnConsultar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_weight="3"

        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_nome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_professor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

        />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_categoria"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

        />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imagemId"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAtualizar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Atualizar"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDeletar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Deletar"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        />


</LinearLayout>



 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imagemId"
     android:layout_width="250dp"
     android:layout_height="250dp"
     android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
     android:src="@drawable/sem_foto"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode iniciar um outro fragment da seguinte:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FrgmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,new Fragment2()).commit();
```

Observe que R.id.fragmentContainer é o seu frameLayout contido no xml e o Fragment2() é o fragmento que você quer chamar;

Comment: Tentei do seu jeito, até que a tela aparece, mas os itens ficam sobrepostos com o da tela anterior. Vou por aqui como ta.

Comment: Agora que caiu a ficha em relação ao container. Consegui. Muito obrigado